# Performing a Join Query with Joins to rows that may not exist

Tags: mysql, join

I have the query:

```
SELECT `gigs`.*, COUNT(`signups`.`signupID`) AS `signupsPending` FROM `gigs` NATURAL JOIN `signups` WHERE (`signupStatus` = 4) GROUP BY `gigID`
```

That is querying a database that looks like this:

```
+-------+---------+------------+
| gigID | gigName | gigDate    |
+-------+---------+------------+
| 1     | Foo     | 01/01/2014 |
+-------+---------+------------+
| 2     | Bar     | 16/01/2014 |
+-------+---------+------------+


+----------+-------+--------------+--------------+
| signupID | gigID | signedUserID | signupStatus |
+----------+-------+--------------+--------------+
| 1        | 1     | 1            | 1            |
+----------+-------+--------------+--------------+
| 2        | 1     | 2            | 4            |
+----------+-------+--------------+--------------+
| 3        | 1     | 3            | 2            |
+----------+-------+--------------+--------------+
| 4        | 2     | 1            | 2            |
+----------+-------+--------------+--------------+
```

But when I do the query above, it only shows a row for gigID = 1. How can I alter the above query so it will show 0 with the rest of the row?

Comment: outer join mate: http://mysql-tips.blogspot.co.uk/2005/04/mysql-outer-join-sql-tutorialexamples.html

Comment: I did try an outer join, but nothing else happened

Comment: sorry mate - terminology ambiguity. `LEFT` and `LEFT OUTER` are the same, and to complicate things I tend to treat `OUTER` and `LEFT` interchangeably (me bad).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been trying OUTER JOIN's, but that has not yielded any results, but I have now tried:

```
SELECT `gigs`.*, COUNT(`signups`.`signupID`) AS `signupsPending` FROM `gigs` LEFT JOIN `signups` ON `gigs`.`gigID` = `signups`.`gigID` AND `signupStatus` = 4 GROUP BY `gigID`
```

And that is working great

Answer (score 0):

Use LEFT OUTER JOIN instead of NATURAL JOIN.

```
SELECT `gigs`.*, COUNT(`signups`.`signupID`) AS `signupsPending` 
FROM `gigs` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `signups` 
WHERE (`signupStatus` = 4) GROUP BY `gigID`
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `LEFT JOIN` (to which you can add `OUTER` for ANSI-92 compatibility)

```
SELECT
  gig.*
, COUNT(sig.signupID) AS "signupsPending"
FROM gigs AS gig
LEFT JOIN signups AS sig ON (gig.gigID = sig.gigID)
WHERE sig.signupStatus = 4
GROUP BY gig.gigID
```

Btw I advise you not to use `NATURAL JOIN` because it brings several risks

- It's based on field names and you may have different field names as foreign keys
- Different foreign keys can be used to JOIN 2 tables (even if you can add a `USING` statement)
- During your database life tables can get field changed added, and you will always have to check that both tables don't get new fields with the same name
- If you use both `NATURAL` and standard `JOIN`s it can be difficult to automate your queries through scripts
- ...

Comment: I did try converting from NATURAL JOIN to LEFT JOIN, but as a matter of principle, I tend to stick to keeping the foreign key ID matching the local key ID, but I get your point

Comment: Also 2 tables are not always JOINt with the same keys.

Comment: I have definately experienced that issue with it throwing the error, field name was ambiguous, even though they where the same, and in those cases, I always use LEFT JOIN's